# How to highlight the cells that satisfies the condition?

Tags: cells, style

```
MemberQ[IntegerDigits [#], 3] & /@ Range[100]

Grid[ArrayReshape[Range[100], {10, 10}], Frame -> All]
```

I want to get a 10 by 10 grid, that highlights all the numbers that have the digit 3. I have done the basic two lines, I am just wondering how to put them togher so that I get something like this

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
Grid[Partition[Item[#, Background -> If[FreeQ[IntegerDigits@#, 3], White, Yellow]] & /@ 
  Range @ 100, 10], ItemSize -> 2, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it, something more efficient probably exists though:

```
bgs = Rule @@@ 
   Transpose[{Tuples[Range[10], 2], 
     If[MemberQ[IntegerDigits[#], 3], Yellow, White] & /@ Range[100]}];
Grid[ArrayReshape[Range[100], {10, 10}], Frame -> All, 
 Background -> {None, None, bgs}]
```

[image: grid with "3"s hilighted]